Alternative gate sets for universal Clifford computation?
The standard universal set of gates for Clifford computation is CNOT, H and S. Are there other options, in particular, gate sets that don't use the S gate?
If yes, what are some examples?


You can choose $CZ$ and/or $CNOT$ gate.
You can choose $\sqrt{X}$ and/or $S$.
Any extension of a generator set is also a generator.
You may find useful to introduce the Pauli operators $X, Y, Z$.


How does one define extension? For example $S = \sqrt{Z}$ multiplied by itself to give $Z$ or $\sqrt{X}$ multiplied by itself to get $X$ is not sufficient to generate all Clifford gates, correct?

$\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{A}$. If $\mathcal{A}$ generates the Clifford group, so does $\mathcal{B}$.
